# connecting yml to html.slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, slim-lang

There are two html.slim files as:

client view:

```
= f.input :name,
        required: true,
        :wrapper => :input_wrapper
```

company view:

```
= f.input :name,
        required: true,
        :wrapper => :input_wrapper
```

there is shared yml file that defines the displayed values as:

```
 simple_form:
        labels:
            defaults:
                name: some value
```

How can I define different name values for the company and the client, ideally without chenging the view? Moreover, how is the yml file linked to the slim file? For example in the routes files it is specified the url and the corresponding view file, how does that work between yml and html.slim files?

Comment: The shared yml file shows default values for label and the slim file you show has only input fields en no label...

Comment: @Hackman you mean that the default value from the yaml file is connected somewhere else, where labels are specified? How can I specify different values for the labels. I thought at first creating a new variable and use that in the company view, but it's not possible because company extends client so I got to use the same variable in the view (name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form) you will find the following:

`simple_form_for @admin_user, as: :some_user` will look into the yml file under `some_user` instead of `admin_user` so the yml file will look like this:

```yaml
en:
  simple_form:
    labels:
        admin_user:
            name: Admin Name
        some_user:
            name: Some user name
```

So in your simple_form you can add `as: :client` and `as: :company` and add those 2 to the yml file.

Comment: Didn't solve the problem directly, however the link to the documentation did the trick, so you got it

Answer (score 0):

You can assign simple form labels like this:

```
en:
  simple_form:
    labels:
      client:
        name: Client name
      company:
        name: Company name
```

Or you can assign attributes like this:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      client:
        name: Client name
      company:
        name: Company name
```